# How are scenes with cannabis plants shot?

Tags: production, props

Presumably, using real cannabis plants would be illegal, but creating huge numbers of fake plastic plants seems expensive, and while I'd imagine they get resold after a shoot, I've never heard of such a thing. So how are scenes featuring pot plants actually filmed?

Comment: If I had to guess, they use hemp plants.

Comment: People can legally grow cannabis too for medical use and in few country it's not illegal.